# Corrected intercorrelations knowing sample size and variable reliabilities

Tags: correlation, meta-analysis, cronbachs-alpha

I have a list of studies from a meta-analysis. The studies list the correlations between two variables (scales, and their reliabilities - alphas), and the N. I am looking to make these correlations comparable. If anyone knows the formula or function that corrects these correlations in terms of variable reliabilities and N, I would really appreciate it. Reviewers are asking me.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an observed correlation $r_{xy}$ and the reliabilities of the components are $r_{xx}$ and $r_{yy}$ then the correlation between the true values is $r_{xy} / (\sqrt{r_{xx}} \sqrt{r_{yy}})$.

However you have Cronbach's $\alpha$ so I wonder whether this classical formula is in fact appropriate. You could (a) try using it and hope (b) try asking the journal to get the referee to explain how s/he thinks you can carry out the correction.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, I will try it. I'm currently reading a book on this, if I find a more precise answer I'll make sure to share it here for everyone to use.